# how to give line break in message in alert dialog box?

Tags: java, android

Using the following code I am unable to break the line to 2.

```
builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b>"+"World"+"</b>+\n+second line"))
```

Result I get like:
`World+ +second line`

Comment: you can use `<br/>` inside `Html.fromHtml()`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `Html.fromHtml()` then use `<br/>` where you want a `line break` for e.g:

```
builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b>"+"World"+"</b><br/>"+"second line"))
```

and if not `Html` and just String you can use `\n` where you want a `line break`.

Answer (score 0):

en..u can use '\n',like that

```
            ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Str1"+"\n"+"Str2"+"\n"+"Str3");
            progressDialog.show();
```

you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it by writing below code :

```
builder.setMessage("First line \n"+"second line"));
```